# nodejs image manipulation with gm / imagemagick

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I'm writing simple app that downloads JPEGs images from Flickr API, and then process them.

All I want to do, is to pick 4 random pixels from each image and save the HEX values.

Is it possible at all? I read a lot of graphicmagick documentation, but can't find a way to do this.

Whats the best way to decode JPEG and get this values? I tried a few plugins but neither can do this by default...

Take care!

Answer (score 0):

https://npmjs.org/package/get-pixels seems nice for that:

```
var getPixels = require("get-pixels")

getPixels("lena.png", function(err, pixels) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("Bad image path")
    return
  }
  console.log("got pixels", pixels.shape)
})
```